# Simple Linear Neural Network Weights from Training are not compatible with training results

Tags: matlab, neural-network

The weights that I get from training, when implied directly on input, return different results! 
I'll show it on a very simple example
let's say we have an input vector `x= 0:0.01:1;`
and target vector `t=x^2` (I know it better to use non linear network)
after training, 2 layer, linear network, with one neuron at each layer, we get:

`sim(net,0.95) =  0.7850` (some error in training - that's ok and should be)
weights from `net.IW,net.LW,net.b:`

IW =

```
0.4547
```

LW =

```
2.1993
```

b =

```
0.3328   -1.0620
```

if I use the weights: Out = purelin(purelin(0.95*IW+b(1))*LW+b(2)) =  0.6200! , I get different result from the result of the sim!
how can it be? what's wrong?

the code:

```
%Main_TestWeights
close all
clear all
clc


t1 = 0:0.01:1;
x = t1.^2;

hiddenSizes = 1;
net = feedforwardnet(hiddenSizes);


[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts,EWs,shift] = preparets(net,con2seq(t1),con2seq(x));
net.layers{1,1}.transferFcn = 'purelin';
[net,tr,Y,E,Pf,Af] = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
view(net);


IW = cat(2,net.IW{1});
LW = cat(2,net.LW{2,1});
b = cat(2,[net.b{1,1},net.b{2,1}]);

%Result from Sim
t2=0.95;
Yk = sim(net,t2)

%Result from Weights
 x1 = IW*t2'+b(1)
 x1out = purelin(x1)
 x2 = purelin(x1out*(LW)+b(2))
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this at all, but could it be that the network normalizes the inputs and targets in some way? If so the reported weights would be useless without applying the same normalization to the inputs yourself. Also, i think you should add in the biases before multiplying with the weights (e.g. ((input+b(1))*IW+b(2))*LW ).

Answer (score 0):

The neural network toolbox rescales inputs and outputs to the [-1,1] range. You must therefore rescale and unscale it so that your simulation output is the same sim()'s output:

```
 %Result from Weights
 x1 = 2*t2 - 1; # rescale 
 x1 = IW*x1+b(1);
 x1out = purelin(x1);
 x2 = purelin(x1out*(LW)+b(2));
 x2 = (x2+1)/2 # unscale
```

then

```
>> x2 == Yk

ans =

     1
```