# Concerns related to matlab neural network toolbox

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I have some concerns related to the use of nntool in matlab toolbox. Following links like these [Simple Linear Neural Network Weights from Training , are not compatable with training results, cant understand why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807184/simple-linear-neural-network-weights-from-training-are-not-compatable-with-tra), I have found that nntool by default normalizes the inputs to the range [-1 1]. So I am a bit concerned, I created a neural network with tansig activation in the first layer and logsig activation in the output layer. I manually normalized the outputs to the range of [0 1] in the data and fed it to nntool. Now my question is does nntool further normalizes it to the range [-1 1]. If it does then it is not correct, the output of logsig cannot be in the range of [-1 1].

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can remove this standard matlab normalization which is applied to both the entries and the outputs. The default is mapminmax. In order to remove it change the OPF argument of `net = newff(P,T,S,TF,BTF,BLF,PF,IPF,OPF,DDF)` to `{'remconstantrows'}`. Personally, I don't like mapminmax very much, its performance is not very good usually. I would consider changing the input normalization to `mapstd` also. You can change this directly also to the network properties if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a matlab user, but if you don't want to use the normalization and it is forced on both input and output - then simply denormalize the output. I assume, that it is simple linear normalization (squashing to the `[-1,1]` interval), so if you want output in the `[0,1]` interval you can simply apply `f(x) = (x+1)/2` which linearly maps `[-1,1]` to the `[0,1]`. Neural networks are scale sensitive (as it is strongly correlated with non-tunable parameters like activation functions slopes), so the internal normalization has its advantages. This should work, if the normalization is applied **after** the training.

If it only normalizes **input** then you should not be concerned, that won't imply any problems with using any activation functions (in fact, as stated before, it should actualy help).

## UPDATE

As the [question has been also posted on the Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69101/concerns-related-to-neural-network-matlab-toolbox/69160#69160), with **more details**, I have answered it there with more precise solution.